# how to match end of line in bash history expansion

Tags: bash

Bash provide a good support for history expansion, for example:

```
echo onetwoone
echo !$
=> onetwoone
```

Also, we can use substitution with it according to `man bash`:

```
echo onetwoone
echo !$:s/one/three/
=> threetwoone
```

At first, I assume this to be similar syntax to `sed`, which however is not the case. I cannot find a way to match the back end of a string.

```
echo onetwoone | sed 's/one$/three/'
=> onetwothree
```

I would like to do the same thing with bash's history expansion:

```
echo onetwoone
echo !$:s/one$/three/
=> -bash: :s/one$/three/: substitution failed
```

Is there any way to achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the [`s`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) modifier doesn't understand regular expressions.

A workaround might be to use `sed`:

```
$ echo onetwoone
onetwoone
```

Use `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/one$/three/' <<< $(echo !$)
sed 's/one$/three/' <<< $(echo onetwoone)
onetwothree
```

---

You may also want to refer to `fc` which enables you to select a command from the `history` and open it in an editor (based on `$EDITOR`) where you could perform the desired manipulation:

```
   fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last]
   fc -s [pat=rep] [cmd]
          Fix Command.  In the first form, a range of commands from  first
          to  last  is selected from the history list.  First and last may
          be specified as a string (to locate the last  command  beginning
          with  that  string)  or  as  a number (an index into the history
          list, where a negative number is used as an offset from the cur‐
          rent command number).  If last is not specified it is set to the
          current command for listing (so that ``fc -l  -10''  prints  the
          last 10 commands) and to first otherwise.  If first is not spec‐
          ified it is set to the previous command for editing and -16  for
          listing.

          The  -n option suppresses the command numbers when listing.  The
          -r option reverses the order of the commands.  If the -l  option
          is  given,  the  commands are listed on standard output.  Other‐
          wise, the editor given by ename is invoked on a file  containing
          those  commands.  If ename is not given, the value of the FCEDIT
          variable is used, and the value of EDITOR if FCEDIT is not  set.
          If  neither  variable  is set, vi is used.  When editing is com‐
          plete, the edited commands are echoed and executed.

          In the second form, command is re-executed after  each  instance
          of  pat  is replaced by rep.  A useful alias to use with this is
          ``r="fc -s"'', so that typing ``r cc''  runs  the  last  command
          beginning with ``cc'' and typing ``r'' re-executes the last com‐
          mand.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually this workaround will not be appropriate if applied to commands like 'mv', 'cp'. `fc` will be a good alternative, but it cannot be applied to "current command" to replace references like "!#:1:s/old/new". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Quoting from the manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Modifiers)

> *s/old/new/*
>
> > Substitute *new* for the first occurrence of *old* in the event line. Any delimiter may be used in place of ‘/’. The delimiter may be quoted in *old* and *new* with a single backslash. If ‘&’ appears in *new*, it is replaced by *old*. A single backslash will quote the ‘&’. The final delimiter is optional if it is the last character on the input line.

It doesn't say anything in there about *old* being a regex or a pattern of any kind.

You could do extra work: replace "one" with "three", repeat the replacement, then replace the first "three" with "one"

```
$ echo onetwoone
onetwoone
$ echo !$:s/one/three/:&:s/three/one
echo onetwothree
onetwothree
```